# Generate sequential number on different objects java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a class like a `"Prepaid Card"` and I need for my card a sequential and unique Id. How can I compare the id of one card that I want to create with the others already created?

Comment: What do you mean by comparing the ids?

Comment: If your creation algorithm will not ensure, that the number is unique, you have no other possibility to compare with all the numbers you have already created. A good algorithm to create unique numbers is counting upwards, and have only one instance of your program produce the number - but I doubt that simple counting will be secure enough for a prepaid card id. What other elements does your card have? Does the number require offline validation? Checksum? Non-predictable sequence?

Comment: Do you need to persist the latest generated ID somehow, i.e. do the IDs need to be unique throughout different runs of the application?

Answer (score -1):

you can maybe use a static AtomicLong ?

```
public class PrepaidCard {

  private static final AtomicLong ref = new AtomicLong();
  private final long counter;

  public PrepaidCard() {
    counter = ref.incrementAndGet();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me, i didn't knew AtomicLong, thanks :D

Comment: What has a concurrency purpose class anything to do with unique identifier generation in a non distributed environment? Why not just use `counter`?

Comment: without context, i have assumed this class could be instanciated from multiples threads. it's just more secure, and the overhead really negligible.